# Exception when Convert.ToDouble on Microsoft SQL Server [C#]

Tags: sql-server, converters

I have a program that first takes the highest value from a SQL Server database using a `MAX` statement.

It get something like: `456.325`. I change the "." with a "," and remove every white space.

I am completly sure that this string can be converted to a double, because it works on my own laptop.

But, when I run the software on a server (2008 R2), it doesn't work. I get a format exception. I tried the `Double.ParseTo` but I doesn't work either.

Code:

```
string str = "";
double d = 0;

while (dataReader.Read())
{
    str = String.Format("{0}", dataReader[0]);

}
str = str.Replace('.', ',');
str = str.Replace(" ", "");
try
{
    d = System.Convert.ToDouble(str);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Can't convert");
}
```

Can it be because of the .NET version on the server ?

Comment: but why comma in place of dot, would that still be meaningful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different regional settings on your laptop and server.

You must specify culture IFormatProvider to get consistent results.